# Should one always write null-proof extension methods in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Imagine we have defined a an extension method that takes this form:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(int arg) { ... }
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
     public static void Baz(this Foo @this)
     {
         @this.Bar(0);// not null-proof
     }
}
```

Here we are exposing a public extension method `Baz` on the `Foo` class (the example is trivial). Now if we have the following usages:

```
Foo foo1 = null;
foo1.Bar(0); // throws NullReferenceException
```

---

```
Foo foo2 = null;
foo2.Baz(); // again throws NullReferenceException
```

So the code in both cases will behave consistently - regardless of calling a member method or extension method we will get the same NullReferenceException() thrown. This makes me feel there is something amiss in the situation. My thoughts are:

- Code that allows `NullReferenceExceptions` is poor, as per most guidelines. The extension method is an example of such bad practice. In order to comply to guidelines and expose a **failure-proof** code as a public API should be, there must be made some null-safety checks like this:

```
    public static void Baz(this Foo @this)
    {
        if (@this == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("@this");
        }
        @this.Bar(0);
    }
```

- Consistency in the behavior will allow the developer to easily detect the null reference situation, since both cases behave the same. I mean, calling an extension method is not always obvious to the coder, so if the line `foo2.Baz()` threw a `NullReferenceException` it is evident that `foo2` is `null`.

The above contradiction lead me to some conclusions. The second point misses an important concern - the stack trace. In a standard `NullPointerException` case, the stack trace leads to the `foo1.Bar(0)` line directly. In the extension method, it will point to the line **from within the extension method** where the exception is thrown. So, the consistent behavior still has an inconsistent stack trace.

And now the question - regarding null-safety, how do "best practices" apply to extension methods that are going to be used by third parties? Should we disregard the consistency by adding argument null-proof validation on the `@this` parameter always? Or is it a corner case that can have us bypass the good practice advices?

**Edit**

I am addressing a situation where a library with the extensions will be exposed. It will not use non-built-in/3rd party solutions like PostSharp or other similar techniques. Also full compatibility with .NET 3.5 is desired.

Comment: Personally, I add `Contract.Requires(@this != null)` in those cases. Checking for nulls higher up the call stack makes it easier to see who is responsible for using the null reference.

Comment: The term `always` scares me on stack overflow. I think this would be more of a holy war than a question that has a definite answer. To me, I would think it would be awkward to get a `NullArgumentException` when the way I am using it feels like an instance method.

Comment: @NickFreeman Why? A lot of extension methods in the .Net framework are going to throw a `ArgumentNullException` if the first parameter is `null`.

Comment: IMO, you're overthinking this.  You should treat extension methods exactly like ordinary static methods in terms of contract obligations and exceptions. (since they're syntactic sugar for just that)  If you think you'd throw the `ArgumentNullException` if you weren't using extension methods, then you should throw it if you *are*.

Comment: @DominicKexel There are 2 sides to an extension method. The writer views it as static and the user views it as instance. The user is the one that is going to have their code with the `Exception`, not the writer, so in my opinion the exception should make sense to the user, not the writer.

Comment: You should actually use `throw new ArgumentNullException("this");`. The `@this` syntax is a C# escape sequence - the true parameter name is simply "this", so that's what you should pass to `ArgumentNullException`. To see what I mean, try adding an `@` sign in front of any identifier (non-keyword) in your program, and you'll see that it still refers to the same declaration.

Comment: the guidelines (reference needed) says that you should throw an exception if `this` is null.  That's probably because extension methods have a different syntax for languages that don't support them in the editor (like vb).  (Sometype)(null).DerpExtension() should behave the same way as DerpExtensions.DerpExtension(null).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how you view extension methods. Given that they are merely syntactic sugar on top of a regular static method, I would say that they should follow guidelines for static methods - check all arguments including the `this` parameter.

This is particularly applicable if you have extensions specifically to handle `null` - I am aware it is not the preferred use of extensions for most people, but I relish methods like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}

public static void DisposeIfNotNull(this IDisposable source)
{
    if (source != null)
        source.Dispose();
}
```

Obviously the parameters must be permitted to be `null` for these methods to work.

Comment: And the ever-popular `public static bool IsNullOrWhitespace(this string text){ return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text); }`

Comment: Good point with the examples. Indeed, sometimes null-safety is the **intention** of an extension method. Also, as per comments on the answer and the point of viewing the extension as a static method (and being invoked as static from non-extension methods enabled CLR language) the checking is a must where applicable. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I write many extension methods that are intended to accept null arguments.  Often times they are mirrors of existing methods on the target classes, but I want to avoid errors if the object on which the method is called is null.  In these cases, I generally name my extensions methods: `...NullSafe(...)` so that when I or others use them, we know they'll return `null` or a default value if the object on which they are called is null.

Answer (score 9):

When I have a problem like this within my organization, I default to convention.

Anyone who has an opinion on this knows what they are talking about. It just depends on whether they look at extension methods from the instance or static side.

I have used WWLD (What would `LINQ` do?) before since it is a common library that uses extension methods that most .NET developer are used to.

Example Code:

```
IEnumerable<int> test = null;
test.Where(t => t > 0); // throws an ArgumentNullException
```

So no matter what my opinion is, I would use `ArgumentNullException` as that is what other .NET developers would be used to.

Comment: Matching what LINQ tends to do in this way I think creates least likelihood of surprise.

Comment: WWLD was new to me, will use that as guidance in my life from now on :)